# Grouping Similar words/phrases

Tags: regex, r, string, nlp, distance

I have a frequency table of words which looks like below

```
> head(freqWords)
    employees          work          bose        people       company 
         1879          1804          1405           971           959 
    employee
          100
> tail(freqWords)
    youll younggood      yoyo       ytd  yuorself      zeal 
        1         1         1         1         1         1
```

I want to create another frequency table which will combine similar words and add their frequencies

In above example, my new table should contain both employee and employees as one element with a frequency of 1979. For example

```
> head(newTable)
    employee,employees          work          bose        people        
         1979                   1804          1405           971           
    company
    959
```

I know how to find out similar words (using `adist`, `stringdist`) but I am unable to create the frequency table. For instance I can use following to get a list of similar words

```
words <- names(freqWords)
lapply(words, function(x) words[stringdist(x, words) < 3])
```

and following to get a list of similar phrases of two words

```
lapply(words, function(x) words[stringdist2(x, words) < 3])
```

where `stringdist2` is follwoing

```
stringdist2 <- function(word1, word2){
    min(stringdist(word1, word2),
        stringdist(word1, gsub(word2, 
                          pattern = "(.*) (.*)", 
                          repl="\\2,\\1")))
}
```

I do not have any punctuation/special symbols in my words/phrases. (I do not know a lot of R; I created `stringdist2` by tweaking an implementation of `adist2` I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961076/how-do-i-group-similar-strings-in-r) but I do not understand everything about how `pattern` and `repl` works)

So I need help to create new frequency table.

Comment: If you use stemming, perhaps from the tm package, you will at least be able to treat words like employee, employees and employer the same.

Comment: Thanks lawyeR, stemming in tm package is exactly what I need for words. But for phrases (two words, three words) I will still need some tweaking. I will try and let you know

Comment: I tried stemming, for single words also it is not exactly what i need. For example It reduces `improving` and `improve` to `improv` which is not what I need. I need either `improve` or `improving` or both (`improve,improving`) If I do stemming then I will have to manually correct all the spellings.

Comment: }Then do stemming but keep an inversed list.

Comment: Thanks Anony, I will try and post here if I have any issues. Still the problem for phrases remain.